# SQL SELECT CASE WHEN Record Is Last in Group Then

Tags: sql, if-statement, select, group-by, case

I'm new to SQL but I have been able to work out the following SQL code with some quick Google searches. However, I can't work out the final step.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,ins_timestamp) AS 'Date' , 
DATEPART(hh,ins_timestamp) AS 'Hour', 
DATEPART(mi, MAX(ins_timestamp) - MIN(ins_timestamp)) + 1 AS 'Minute', 
database.Terminal_no, 
database.Prod_code, 
Sum(database.Curr_boxes) AS 'Sum of Curr_Boxes' 

FROM database

WHERE (database.From_ord_type=1) AND (database.ins_timestamp Between ? And ?)

GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,ins_timestamp) , 
DATEPART(hh,ins_timestamp), 
database.Terminal_no, 
database.Prod_code


union all


SELECT CONVERT(DATE,ins_timestamp) AS 'Date', 
DATEPART(hh,ins_timestamp) AS 'Hour' , 
DATEPART(mi, MAX(ins_timestamp) - MIN(ins_timestamp)) + 1 AS 'Minute',  
database.Terminal_no, database.Prod_code, 
-Sum(database.Curr_boxes) AS 'Sum of Curr_Boxes' 

FROM database

WHERE (database.to_status='VOID') and (database.ins_timestamp Between ? And ?)

GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,ins_timestamp), 
DATEPART(hh,ins_timestamp), 
database.Terminal_no, 
database.Prod_code
```

For the Minutes, I'm trying to use something similar to an IF statement (which I believe to be a Case statement) in the Select section to see whether the record is the last in the group. This is because I could have multiple rows for each grouping specified if we have more than one product that run in a specific hour.

If this is the case then I would like to add on a number which is to be calculated as 60 minutes minus the total minutes of the records returned in the grouping to the last minute record in the grouping. See example below:

| Date | Hour | Minute | Terminal_no | Prod_code | Sum of Curr_Boxes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14/04/21 | 7 | 9 | 1 | 12S | 103 |
| 14/04/21 | 7 | 27 | 1 | 13S | 365 |
| 14/04/21 | 7 | **18** | 1 | 14S | 223 |
| 14/04/21 | 7 | 37 | 2 | 24S | 121 |
| 14/04/21 | 7 | **19** | 2 | 26S | 221 |

The total of the minutes in the first grouping for Terminal_no 1 is 54. So I would like to add on 6 minutes (60 - 54) to the last record of the grouping to show 24. In the last grouping the last minute record should then be 23 (= 19 + (60 - 56)) :

| Date | Hour | Minute | Terminal_no | Prod_code | Sum of Curr_Boxes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14/04/21 | 7 | 9 | 1 | 12S | 103 |
| 14/04/21 | 7 | 27 | 1 | 13S | 365 |
| 14/04/21 | 7 | **24** | 1 | 14S | 223 |
| 14/04/21 | 7 | 37 | 2 | 24S | 121 |
| 14/04/21 | 7 | **23** | 2 | 26S | 221 |

Comment: Please tag your DB.